# Выдает ошибку "Нет доступных экземпляров типа Number". Как решить?

Tags: java, классы

```
public abstract class Number {
    private double number;

    public Number(double number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public double getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public abstract void display();

    public abstract void plusNumbers();

    public abstract void minusNumbers();

    public abstract void mulNumbers();

    public abstract void divNumbers();

    
    public class Integer extends Number {
        private int integerNumber;

        public Integer(double number, int integerNumber) {
            super(number);
            this.integerNumber = integerNumber;
        }

        public int getIntegerNumber() {
            return integerNumber;
        }

        public void setIntegerNumber(int integerNumber) {
            this.integerNumber = integerNumber;
        }

        public void display() {
            System.out.printf("Number: %s", super.getNumber());
        }

        public void plusNumbers() {
            System.out.printf("%s + %s = %s", super.getNumber(), integerNumber,
                    super.getNumber() + (double) integerNumber);
        }

        public void minusNumbers() {
            System.out.printf("%s - %s = %s", super.getNumber(), integerNumber,
                    super.getNumber() - (double) integerNumber);
        }

        public void mulNumbers() {
            System.out.printf("%s * %s = %s", super.getNumber(), integerNumber,
                    super.getNumber() * (double) integerNumber);
        }

        public void divNumbers() {
            System.out.printf("%s / %s = %s", super.getNumber(), integerNumber,
                    super.getNumber() / (double) integerNumber);
        }
    }

    public class Real extends Number {
        private double realNumber;

        public Real(double number, double realNumber) {
            super(number);
            this.realNumber = realNumber;
        }

        public double getRealNumber() {
            return realNumber;
        }

        public void setRealNumber(double realNumber) {
            this.realNumber = realNumber;
        }

        public void display() {
            System.out.printf("Number: %s", super.getNumber());
        }

        public void plusNumbers() {
            System.out.printf("%s + %s = %s", super.getNumber(), realNumber, super.getNumber() + realNumber);
        }

        public void minusNumbers() {
            System.out.printf("%s - %s = %s", super.getNumber(), realNumber, super.getNumber() - realNumber);
        }

        public void mulNumbers() {
            System.out.printf("%s * %s = %s", super.getNumber(), realNumber, super.getNumber() * realNumber);
        }

        public void divNumbers() {
            System.out.printf("%s / %s = %s", super.getNumber(), realNumber, super.getNumber() / realNumber);
        }
    }

    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        Real realNum = new Real(4.0, 4.1);

        realNum.plusNumbers();
    }

}
```

При запуске программы выдает ошибку:

[image: Ошибка при запуске программы]

Смотрел примеры. Искал ошибку в гугле. Но смог найти. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: А почему внутри абстрактного класса объявили его потомков? Так обычно не делают, думаю, если вы классы `Real` и `Integer` вытащите из `Number`, то код будет без ошибок компилироваться. Кст, в самой ошибке написано как ее можно решить, т.е. `Number.new Real(4.0, 4.1)`, хотя это выглядит странно, я бы предположил, что должно быть: `new Number.Real(4.0, 4.1)`

Comment: У меня есть еще вариант где классы `Real` и `Integer` вне класса `Number`. Там тоже такая же ошибка. Сделал все как вы сказали. Но проблема остался таким же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мои действия:

1. Создал файл `Number.java` с классом `Number` и вложенными в него `Integer` и `Real`.
2. Вынес классы `Integer` и `Real` из класса `Number`
3. Убрал у них `public`, чтобы не создавать для них отдельные файлы (можете этот пункт не выполнять, но сделать им файлы: `Integer.java` и `Real.java`)
4. Исправил название метода `main`

Пример:

```
public abstract class Number {
    private double number;

    public Number(double number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public double getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public abstract void display();

    public abstract void plusNumbers();

    public abstract void minusNumbers();

    public abstract void mulNumbers();

    public abstract void divNumbers();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Real realNum = new Real(4.0, 4.1);
        realNum.plusNumbers();
        // 4.0 + 4.1 = 8.1

        System.out.println();

        Number num = new Real(4.0, 4.1);
        num.plusNumbers();
        // 4.0 + 4.1 = 8.1
    }
}

class Integer extends Number {
    private int integerNumber;

    public Integer(double number, int integerNumber) {
        super(number);
        this.integerNumber = integerNumber;
    }

    public int getIntegerNumber() {
        return integerNumber;
    }

    public void setIntegerNumber(int integerNumber) {
        this.integerNumber = integerNumber;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.printf("Number: %s", super.getNumber());
    }

    public void plusNumbers() {
        System.out.printf("%s + %s = %s", super.getNumber(), integerNumber,
                super.getNumber() + (double) integerNumber);
    }

    public void minusNumbers() {
        System.out.printf("%s - %s = %s", super.getNumber(), integerNumber,
                super.getNumber() - (double) integerNumber);
    }

    public void mulNumbers() {
        System.out.printf("%s * %s = %s", super.getNumber(), integerNumber,
                super.getNumber() * (double) integerNumber);
    }

    public void divNumbers() {
        System.out.printf("%s / %s = %s", super.getNumber(), integerNumber,
                super.getNumber() / (double) integerNumber);
    }
}

class Real extends Number {
    private double realNumber;

    public Real(double number, double realNumber) {
        super(number);
        this.realNumber = realNumber;
    }

    public double getRealNumber() {
        return realNumber;
    }

    public void setRealNumber(double realNumber) {
        this.realNumber = realNumber;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.printf("Number: %s", super.getNumber());
    }

    public void plusNumbers() {
        System.out.printf("%s + %s = %s", super.getNumber(), realNumber, super.getNumber() + realNumber);
    }

    public void minusNumbers() {
        System.out.printf("%s - %s = %s", super.getNumber(), realNumber, super.getNumber() - realNumber);
    }

    public void mulNumbers() {
        System.out.printf("%s * %s = %s", super.getNumber(), realNumber, super.getNumber() * realNumber);
    }

    public void divNumbers() {
        System.out.printf("%s / %s = %s", super.getNumber(), realNumber, super.getNumber() / realNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: Отлично. Сработало. Спасибо вам))

Comment: @LeskhanMuratuly, пожалуйста :)